# Java client server sending bytes receiver listens indefinitely

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I'm trying to write a Java program for Windows that involves communication with a server program located on a foreign machine.My program successfully connects to the server, successfully writes a byte array to it, and waits for a response.

I know that the server is printing bytes (the response) back to me one byte at a time. I've tried using a DataInputStream object with various methods (read, readByte etc.), I've tried using a BufferedReader object with its methods (read, readLine etc.) but all the reader objects and various methods that I've used all come up against the same problem.

The bytes are being successfully read (each time a byte or bytes are read, I can print them to the console, and they are what I'd expect them to be). The problem is that my reader doesn't know when to stop reading. Even if the server has sent all its bytes, the reader function on my end waits for more data, indefinitely, and so the program hangs at the read function.

This problem seems to affect all the techniques that I have tried. I've been running tests with a simple client program and server program, each about 40 or 50 lines long, where the client connects to the server, and sends some bytes to it. All the techniques I've tried for the server reader result in the same problem mentioned above (the server hangs waiting for more input from the client, even though it has sent all its data).

I'm really desperate for some help on this. It's important that I get this program finished soon, and it's basically complete except for this communication issue. Any help is much appreciated!

-Rob

--EDIT--

In the end, I settled for an algorithm that terminates the reading of bytes by keeping track of the number of message segments that have been read (segments are delimited by two null values: 00) and comparing that with the number of expected segments (passed to the read function as an argument). Its not an ideal method, but it works, and I don't have time to work on the program any longer.

Thanks for everyones help!

Comment: Are you closing your streams?

Comment: I did try closing the writer object on the client end after sending the data in the client-server test programs, and it worked, but the server then caused a runtime exception saying that the connection was closed when it tried to create a DataOutputStream object to write a response to the client. But in the actual program that I'm trying to write, I don't have control over what the server does or doesn't do.

Comment: Also, sending the length of the data in advance is not an option, because the server I'm contacting doesn't do that, and I dont have control over the server code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option (not so great, but it sounds like you might be down to it) is to try to act on the received data.  For example, if you're receiving a serialized object, you could try to deserialized it.  If it succeeds, you've received all of your data.  If not, try to read some more.

Can you tell us more about what sort of data you're receiving?  Is there anything in the data that you can examine to determine if the message is complete?

Comment: The program is actually an implementation of the Otway-Rees security protocol. 3 parties involved: ClientA, ClientB and Server. A and B want to communicate with each other, so they use the server to authenticate them AND provide a session key they can both use for communication. It's a final year college assignment, and my implementations must be interoperable with my lecturers reference implementations. The messages passed around are encoded using NT encoding (Null Terminated encoding). Each part of the message ends with 00. But there can be a variable number of parts to a message. Hmm...

Comment: when you say variable number of parts, is there no previous indication in the protocol as to the actual number of parts that are going to arrive?

Comment: Well, yes actually, there is. Thats a good point. If the messages are sent appropriately, then there should be a fixed number of NT encoded segments to the message. It's worth looking into, but I cant help but feel that its just wrong. I really should be able to have a generic function for reading data from another entity.

Comment: It's not uncommon for protocols to require at least some inspection of the content to know when it's all received. If you want to reuse connections (connection creation is pretty expensive), then you really need to do something based on the content. Often that will be a content length in a header, but you're definitely constrained by what the server does. This one might be kind of expensive (since you have to check ~all of the chars to see if they're null (since multiple segments could presumably come in a packet), but I don't see a better way. (which is not to say that there isn't one!).

Answer (score 1):

Its you who defines the end condition.

One common, simple case is simple closing the connection (this is the definition of the P9100 printing protocol). The read should return -1 now.

Otherwise you can

- prefix your data with a length. The server stops reading after n bytes received
- terminate the data with a dedicated byte. The server stops receiving when the marker byte is found.

Is this your problem or did i misunderstand?

Answer (score 1):

You either need the server to close the connection, or you need to be able to tell from the data that the server's message is finished - perhaps using a special byte (e.g. a zero byte), or by sending the length of the data before the data itself.

Otherwise, there's no way the application can tell the difference between the server having finished sending its data (and waiting for the next request), and the server pausing in the middle of sending its data.

Answer (score 0):

So your application can continue running you could read the response data in a separate thread.

If there really is no other way to know when the message has finished you can use a time-out. i.e. once you get data and you haven't received any more for 100 ms or 1 second you might assume you have it all.

A better alternative is you write your code so it doesn't need to know when the end of the message is.  It could just process each "response" as it gets them, treating them as streaming events as they arrive.

The way the data comes back, it appears to assume you don't need to know when the data is complete.